# SEVERE: https://jenkins.domainname.com/tcpSlaveAgentListener/ appears to be publishing an invalid X-Instance-Identity

Tags: jenkins

We're trying to connect a previously connected agent to a Jenkins server.

We get the following error:

```
SEVERE: https://jenkins.domainname.com/tcpSlaveAgentListener/ appears to be publishing an invalid X-Instance-Identity.
java.io.IOException: https://jenkins.domainname.com/tcpSlaveAgentListener/ appears to be publishing an invalid X-Instance-Identity.
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:287)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:694)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:519)
```

The command to run the agent is:

> java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://${private_ip}:8080/computer/mac/slave-agent.jnlp -secret ${secret} -workDir "/var/jenkins-sign"

- We're running on a MacOS.
- All TCP ports are open internally between the mac and the ${private_ip}. I have telnet working.
- As said, this agent was recently connected to the server, but the agent had a restart. We also upgraded the Jenkins server to latest available version.
- I updated the agent.jar file.
- I think it's related to contacting ${private_ip} while the X-Instance-Identit says "jenkins.dommainame.com", but I am not sure how to resolve it.
- I only saw that there were recently changes in this area, but not a lot of helpful information other than that.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else runs into the issue, in my case it was because I was passing the entire URL, i.e.

http://someurl/jenkins/computer/test/slave-agent.jnlp

and what it really wanted was

http://someurl/jenkins/

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I will try it out next time I'm on that system.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think it's related to Jenkins upgrade that caused this, and I'm not sure there's a better solution than what I found.

Putting here my solution, but if anyone knows something better, I'd be happy to hear about it :)

- Download the agent.jar
- Download the slave-agent.jnlp and modify it:

  - Change all occurrences of `https://jenkins.mydomain.com` to `http://[private_ip]:[port]`.
- Start the process: `java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl "file:/path/to/dir/slave-agent.jnlp" -workDir "/path/to/dir"`

  - Do not add the secret to this command.
  - If you're using Jenkins agent as a service, remove the -secret argument from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Set global environment variable **jenkins.agent.inboundUrl** to your private adderess (with http/https) + port + suffix (if set).

This value will be used as url in JNLP file. This enables using a private address for inbound tcp agents, separate from Jenkins root URL.

see: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-63222

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with generate SSH key on agent host and create SSH credential on Jenkins controller. Following instructions of this official manual: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/