# Jenkins node / agent not able to connect to master jenkins server - invalid X-Instance-Identity

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

We are trying to setup the Jenkins master and slave on the Openshift environment by importing YAMLs of storage, service, master and slave nodes (Ref - https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/).

We are using **Jenkins LTS 2.263.1** and **agent version 4.3-7-jdk11** docker images.
Jenkins master pod is up and running and available with no issues. We are facing issue when we setup the slave node.

Steps followed while setting up slave node,

1. Create agent node from master node (from UI) by adding home root dir and other standard configurations
2. Import YAML to Openshift

After importing YAML, while starting pod, we receive following error

```
INFO: Locating server among [https://myjenkins.company.com/ ]
Dec 16, 2020 4:26:19 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: https://myjenkins.company.com/tcpSlaveAgentListener/  appears to be publishing an invalid X-Instance-Identity.
java.io.IOException: https://myjenkins.company.com/tcpSlaveAgentListener/  appears to be publishing an invalid X-Instance-Identity.
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:287)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:693)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:518)
```

We tried launching the slave node by various ways but no luck.

- https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/215578778-How-to-fix-an-instance-having-an-invalid-identity-key-enc-file-
- [SEVERE: https://jenkins.domainname.com/tcpSlaveAgentListener/ appears to be publishing an invalid X-Instance-Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64015197/severe-https-jenkins-domainname-com-tcpslaveagentlistener-appears-to-be-publ)

When we hit the https://myjenkins.company.com/tcpSlaveAgentListener/ URL from browser, we get "Jenkins" as response and response headers has "x-instance-identity" with some value.

Do you know what's going wrong here?
Are we missing something in the setup?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64015197/severe-https-jenkins-domainname-com-tcpslaveagentlistener-appears-to-be-publ/71407634#71407634

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this issue by changing the Jenkins URL in the configurations.
As our Jenkins master pod and agent nodes (pods) are in same openshift namespace, we are able to configure the service URLs instead of actual route URL.

You can get the service name from Openshift which is created for your master Jenkins route.

For me route URL - https://myjenkins.company.com/
Service URL - http://ouropenshift.myservice.name.svc.cluster.local:8080/

> Manager Jenkins -> configure System -> Jenkins URL -> http://ouropenshift.myservice.name.svc.cluster.local:8080/

Instead of giving https://myjenkins.company.com as URL, we gave HTTP service URL.
eg. http://ouropenshift.myservice.name.svc.cluster.local:8080/

2 Things to notice, HTTP protocol and port.

Some how jenkins agent is not able to hit the real Jenkins URLs and match the headers.

Thanks